# Google Play Store: can refunded apps still be used and updated?

Tags: google-play

As far as I know this is not documented by Google.

What happens when the developer manually refunds a paid app purchase, using the Order Management console (like shown below) ?

Can the user still use it and receive udpates?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the purchase price for a Paid app is refunded then Play will remove the app from the user's library. This means future checks that depend on app ownership (eg the [Play License Verification Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/overview)) will return the app is not purchased. However, the app isn't guaranteed to be removed from the user's device, which is why use of the license verification library is recommended.

For refunds around in app purchases and subscriptions the answer might be different. Your question isn't completely clear about whether it is buying a paid app or an IAP/Subscription, but I think you are asking about a paid app.

Comment: Yes, I was referring about paid apps.

Answer (score 0):

it would be trivial to pay for and install the app, then make the phone go into airplane mode and do a refund from your desktop, thus extending the period of time the app could be used well beyond 2 hours. But of course as soon as you go back on line the app would get uninstalled as soon as the play store checked in with google, which happens even if you don't actively open the play store.